# PartitionKey property in Cosmos DB needs to be a string always?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am serializing and storing the below class object into a Cosmos DB partitioned collection with partition key path "/targetId" set on the collection.

```
public class DataItem
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    /// This is my partition key
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "targetId")]
    public long TargetId { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class, when I have the property TagretId as long, I get error the below error:

```
Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other 
than the one for which client request was submitted
```

However, when I change the TargetId property to type "string", it works fine.

Is there any type restrcition on the partition key property while using it with Cosmos DB?

**Updated code**

```
List<DataItem> items = GetDataItems();  // This comes from UI as JSON, actually
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(x => x.TargetId);
foreach (var groupItem in groupedItems)
{
    // I even tried like below converting to dynamic JSON array. Still got the same exception
    //string argsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupItem.ToArray());
    //var args = new dynamic[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(argsJson) };

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(groupItem.Key.ToString()) };

    var result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int>(
        UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, sprocId),
        requestOptions,
        groupItem.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Would you please share the code you did operations to cosmos db? Per my experience , partition key has no type restrcition.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have updated the post with code I am using to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: Have you tried passing the long value as the PartitionKey vs. passing the ToString() value?

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB allows partition key to be number. But it looks EF Core needs to make sure partition key field can be converted to string.

I found this way can solve the problem.

builder.Property(p => p.MyProperty).ToJsonProperty("myProperty")
.HasConversion();